# Stop fixed sidebar at footer - prevent overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

A sidebar becomes fixed after 400 pixels from top. Therefore I use this code found on stack:

```
<div id="gettop"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
function fixDiv() {
var $cache = $('#gettop');
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400)
  $cache.css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    'top': '8px',
    'margin-left': '20px',
    'border': '1px solid #ccc'
  });
else
  $cache.css({
    'position': 'relative',
    'top': 'auto'
  });
}
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
fixDiv();
});
```

The Code works great. But the sidebar is overlapping the footer. How can I prevent this?

I tried some code I found here without success.

[How to prevent fixed button from overlapping footer area and stop the button on top of where the footer is located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053326/how-to-prevent-fixed-button-from-overlapping-footer-area-and-stop-the-button-on)

[Stop fixed position at footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653025/stop-fixed-position-at-footer)

[Fixed sidebar on the scroll stop at div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408441/fixed-sidebar-on-the-scroll-stop-at-div)

I am quite sure, that I made a mistake in mixing the codes.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give bigger z-index to the element you want to be on top.